# Using FastAPI in a sync way, how can I get the raw body of a POST request?

Tags: python, fastapi, starlette

Using FastAPI in a **sync**, not `async` mode, I would like to be able to receive the raw, unchanged body of a POST request.

All examples I can find show `async` code, when I try it in a normal sync way, the `request.body()` shows up as a coroutine object.

When I test it by posting some `XML` to this endpoint, I get a `500 "Internal Server Error"`.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, Request, Body

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

@app.post("/input")
def input_request(request: Request):
    # how can I access the RAW request body here?  
    body = request.body()

    # do stuff with the body here  

    return Response(content=body, media_type="application/xml")
```

Is this not possible with FastAPI?

Note: a simplified input request would look like:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:1083/input
Content-Type: application/xml

<XML>
    <BODY>TEST</BODY>
</XML>
```

and I have no control over how input requests are sent, because I need to replace an existing SOAP API.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Using `async def` endpoint

If an object is a co-routine, it needs to be awaited. [FastAPI is actually Starlette underneath](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/), and [Starlette methods](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body) for returning the request `body` are `async` methods (see the source code [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/requests.py#L231) as well); thus, one needs to `await` them (inside an `async def` endpoint). For example:

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.post("/input")
async def input_request(request: Request):
    return await request.body()
```

### Update 1 - Using `def` endpoint

Alternatively, if you are confident that the incoming data is a valid `JSON`, you can define your endpoint with `def` instead, and use the [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/) field, as shown below (for more options on how to post `JSON` data, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804)):

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post("/input")
def input_request(payload: dict = Body(...)):
    return payload
```

If, however, the incoming data are in `XML` format, as in the example you provided, one option is to pass them using [`Files`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) instead, as shown below—as long as you have control over how client data are sent to the server (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) as well). Example:

```py
from fastapi import File

@app.post("/input") 
def input_request(contents: bytes = File(...)): 
    return contents
```

### Update 2 - Using `def` endpoint and `async` dependency

As described in [this post](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2574#issuecomment-751787209), you can use an `async` [dependency](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) function to pull out the `body` from the request. You can use `async` dependencies on `non-async` (i.e., `def`) endpoints as well. Hence, if there is some sort of blocking code in this endpoint that prevents you from using [`async`/`await`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/)—as I am guessing this might be the reason in your case—this is the way to go.

Note: I should also mention that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)—which explains the difference between `def` and `async def` endpoints (that you might be aware of)—also provides solutions when you are required to use `async def` (as you might need to `await` for coroutines inside a route), but also have some *synchronous* expensive CPU-bound operation that might be blocking the server. Please have a look.

Example of the approach described earlier can be found below. You can uncomment the `time.sleep()` line, if you would like to confirm yourself that a request won't be blocking other requests from going through, as [when you declare an endpoint with normal `def` instead of `async def`, it is run in an external threadpool](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/#path-operation-functions) (regardless of the `async def` dependency function).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request
import time

app = FastAPI()

async def get_body(request: Request):
    return await request.body()

@app.post("/input")
def input_request(body: bytes = Depends(get_body)):
    print("New request arrived.")
    #time.sleep(5)
    return body
```

Comment: In sync there's no await, that's why I'm asking. FastAPI supports sync requests after all...

Comment: I'll check and get back to this

Comment: the "File" approach returns "HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity". I added an example request to the original question. Note: I can't control how clients requests look like because I'm recreating a legacy SOAP API to be able to re-route the request from the legacy system to a Python service that will replace the old service.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting this. Update #2 works for me (using FastAPI 0.79.0 and Python 3.10.5 on Windows 10) - it also works fine if several requests are made at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, you can simply use `asgiref`, this package supports `async_to_sync` and `sync_to_async`:

```py
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync

sync_body_func = async_to_sync(request.body)
print(sync_body_func())
```

`async_to_sync` execute an async function in an eventloop, `sync_to_async` execute a sync function in a threadpool.