# FastAPI: How to upload a file without using multipart/form-data request?

Tags: python, file-upload, fastapi, starlette

I have a FastAPI endpoint for handling file uploads that looks something like this:

```py
@app.post('/upload')
async def accept_some_file(f: UploadFile):
    content = await f.read()
    # ... do stuff with content and generate a response
```

but this appears to only work with `multipart/form-data` encoded payloads.

I'd like to be able to send file bytes directly through a request that looks like this:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: curl/7.79.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 11044

... image bytes
```

Is there a FastAPI setting I can use to allow this? Or is there another request type that makes more sense for this use case?

Comment: This question helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi

Comment: No, that question involves using `multipart/form-data` as the upload encoding. I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1

You could get the request body as `bytes` using `await request.body()`. If you would like to do that in the *synchronous* way (i.e., using `def` endpoint instead—see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for `def` vs `async def`), please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804).

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.post('/upload')
async def upload_file(request: Request):
    body = await request.body()
```

### Option 2

You could also access the request body as a `stream`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) (under "Update" section) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804) (which provides another working example, demonstrating how to receive both Files and Form data using `request.stream()`). In this way, the byte chunks are provided without first storing the entire body to memory (see [Starlette's documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body) as well)—in contrast to using `request.body()`, as shown in the previous option, which could lead to issues, if the request body (e.g., a file) couldn't fit into the server's RAM.

Note that the example below stores the byte chunks in a variable named `body` (essentially, storing them into RAM), but that's for demo purposes. If, however, you need to write the byte chunks to the disk as they arrive, please have a look at the linked answers above on how to do so using `aiofiles` or `streaming_form_data` libraries.

```py
@app.post('/upload')
async def upload_file(request: Request):
    body = b''
    async for chunk in request.stream():
        body += chunk
```