# Parsing raw multipart/form data with FastAPI

Tags: python, forms, http, fastapi, sendgrid

### Context

I'd like to use FastAPI to ingest SendGrid's [inbound parse webhook](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/parsing-email/setting-up-the-inbound-parse-webhook), which comes in as a raw multipart/form-data (see below). My code is receiving the payload, but I get a "422 unprocessable entity" error when I try to parse it with FastAPI (indicating Pydantic rejects it).

**Is there a way to parse this kind of data with FastAPI, or do I need to do so manually and then pass it to FastAPI in a different format?** (If so, a FastAPI example would be much appreciated)

### Minimal Reproducible Example

Simple FastAPI app to receive the data:

```py
from typing import Any
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/inbound_email")
async def inbound_email(
    headers: Any = Form(...),
    subject: Any = Form(...),
    ):
    try:
        print(headers)
        print(subject)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"inbound_email exception: {e}")

# Make code accessible to the web: I'm starting uvicorn on a port I've told ngrok to listen to
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("min_reproducible_example:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=54200, reload=True)
```

SendGrid docs contain a full [sample of the webhook payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77153861/parsing-raw-multipart-form-data-with-fastapi#:%7E:text=inbound%20parse%20webhook), but to simplify I'll use a truncated version for our example (keeping the --xYzZY s consistent).

Here's the `curl` from zsh terminal:

```
curl --location 'https://myurlhere.ngrok-free.app/inbound_email' \
--data '--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000021b9ea0605bbd8ac"

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Inbound test 5
--xYzZY--
'
```

The app prints:

> "POST /inbound_email HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

If I make the same request from Postman, I get a more detailed response from the app:

```
*422 Unprocessable Entry*
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "type": "missing",
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "headers"
            ],
            "msg": "Field required",
            "input": null,
            "url": "https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.3/v/missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm wondering if SendGrid's raw multipart format is something FastAPI doesn't have the tools to parse, as if I try to parse the `request` directly into `headers` and `subject`, I am unsuccessful:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/inbound_email")
async def inbound_email(
    request: Request,
    ):
    try:
        # Access the raw request body
        raw_body = await request.body()
        print(raw_body.decode("utf-8"))
        # Access the form data directly from request.form()
        form_data = await request.form()
        body_headers = form_data.get("headers")
        subject = form_data.get("subject")
        print("body_headers:", body_headers)
        print("subject:", subject)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"inbound_email exception: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("min_reproducible_example:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=54200, reload=True)
```

Terminal output is:

```
--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="headers"

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="00000000000021b9ea0605bbd8ac"

--xYzZY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subject"

Inbound test 5
--xYzZY--

body_headers: None
subject: None
```

#### A few additional notes:

When sending from Postman, I send body text in "raw" format, with the default headers. (I have tried other headers explicitly specifying format, boundary etc, but that hasn't worked).

Noteably, I can send POST requests to FastAPI in any other format (including Postman's "form-data") and get everything to work. It's just this raw text format that I can't get to parse.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]. In particular, it would be helpful if you would update your question to include a complete example HTTP request, or alternatively a `curl` command line that produces the same format so we have some way of reproducing the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks @larsks - I've added detail . Still learning "how much is enough", so I appreciate the input.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) answer your question? You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72062813/17865804) helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. This got me pointed in the right direction. For future readers - I swapped to a provider with a JSON-based webhook so don't have a concrete solution to post, but Chris's comment is effectively the answer.