# How can I upload a file more then 1 MB using Form Data in fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, multipartform-data

The problem is that I am trying to post a file (pdf, jpg etc.) more then 1MB from the user (I am using postman).
The thing is I have to use the form data (don't use the JSON) I am getting the content of form data from the request body using `request.from()` [ref](https://www.starlette.io/requests/).

```
@router.post("/document_upload/")
async def upload_files(request:Request):
    content_type = request.headers['content-type']
    pattren = r'multipart/form-data'
    if request.headers['content-type'] == "application/json":
        data = await request.json()
        return Utiles.json_data(data)    
    elif re.search(pattren,content_type):
        data = await request.form() 
        return Utiles.form_data(data)
    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        detail= "Invalide Content-type"
    )
```

in the elif at

```
data = await request.form()
```

This line:
I am getting the

> multipart.exceptions.MultipartParseError: Did not find boundary character 154 at index 2

**Utiles.json_data(data) => if user send json data**

```
   def json_data(data):
        img_base64_bytes = base64.b64decode(data["image"])
        buffer = io.BytesIO(img_base64_bytes)
        return AWS.updoad(data, buffer)
```

**Utiles.form_data(data) => if user send form-data**

```
def form_data(data):
        upload_file = data["file"]
        file_data = upload_file.file.read()
        buffer = io.BytesIO(file_data)
        return AWS.updoad(data, buffer)
```

**AWS.updoad(data, buffer)**

```
def updoad(data,buffer):
        fileinfo = filetype.guess(buffer) #the argument can be buffer or file
        ext = fileinfo.extension
        ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = ["jpg", "jpeg","pdf","doc","docx"]
        buffer.seek(0)
        print(ext)
        if ext not in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                                detail="This Extension is not allowed ")
        s3_client = boto3.client(
                service_name = settings.SERVICE_NAME,
                aws_access_key_id = settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                aws_secret_access_key = settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
            )
        try:
            s3_client.upload_fileobj(buffer,"bucket-name",f"Document/{date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")}/{data["claim_id"]}/{data["claim_type"]}/{data["user"]+data["user_age"]+"."+ext }",ExtraArgs={'Metadata': {'type': 'jpg'}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        })
            buffer.close()
        except Exception:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    
        return {"filename": f"{data["user"]+data["user_age"]+"."+ ext}"}
```

**Ask if you need more details**

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the built in Form-support in FastAPI or `UploadFile` if you're receiving files through standard HTTP posts? You're reimplementing whatever Starlette / FastAPI can do automagically for you.

Comment: if i use the **UploadFile** i still can't post the file more then **1MB** i have use the request method because user can send data in any form ( in json or form-data ) so for that i am not using the uploadfile

Comment: In that case it sounds like the issue is in front of your starlette/fastapi instance. Do you have nginx/a cdn/etc. in front of your service, or are you running with uvicorn locally?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72062813/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804). Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804)

Comment: i am using uvicorn to run it locally and postman to test the api

Comment: thank u @Chris this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74009210/how-to-create-a-fastapi-endpoint-that-can-accept-either-form-or-json-body/74015930#74015930)  option 1 help's me and my problem is resolve