# Access request.body() parameters without async await in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to receive body parameters from ajax call without using async on backend route.

When doing async It is working fine:

```
@app.post('/process-form')
async def process_form(request : Request):
    # Access form data
    form_data = await request.body()
    da = jsonable_encoder(form_data)
    print(da)
```

But without async body() does not exist (vs code debugger) and it is awaitable or something:

```
@app.post('/process-form')
def process_form(request : Request):
    # Access form data
    form_data = request.body()
    da = jsonable_encoder(form_data)
    print(da)
```

```
site-packages\anyio\streams\memory.py", line 89, in receive_nowait
    raise WouldBlock
anyio.WouldBlock
```

Why is it so and how Could I receive my data from request?

Answer (score 1):

Does the following code accomplish what you are looking for?

```py
# foo.py

from asyncio import run
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/')
def process_form(request: Request):
    body = run(request.body())
    print(body)
```

I run the app with:

```bash
$ uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9999 --reload foo:app
```

And test with:

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:9999/ -XPOST --data-raw 'hello world'
```

---

The key is to use [`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) (documentation for `python3.9`) to "execute synchronously" coroutines and tasks.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to have a sync end-point and access the payload:

```
@app.post('/process-form')
def process_form(form_data: Any, request : Request):
    # Access form data
    print(form_data)
```

`form_data` will contain the data you send as a payload to your request.
You'll need to correctly type `form_data`

I think this post is similar to your question [Using FastAPI in a sync way, how can I get the raw body of a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70658748/using-fastapi-in-a-sync-way-how-can-i-get-the-raw-body-of-a-post-request)