# Get body of request in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to get the full body of every request in fastapi.

So this code works fine but it does not print the full body:

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def print_request(request: Request, call_next):
        request_str = {}
        for i in request:
            request_str[i] = request[i]
        print(request_str)
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response
```

For example:

```
@router.put("/backend/edit_service")
async def router_edit_service(user_id: int,
                              service: EditService):
    return edit_service(db=db, service=service, user_id=user_id)
```

It just show user_id but not the parameters of EditService

Comment: I think it is about the pydantic model not the request. So how to access the model and print it in request?

Comment: You can read the actual body with `await request.body()` - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Hamed In addition to the link provided above, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804).

Comment: The problem is how to process request.body(), anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69670125/how-to-log-raw-http-request-response-in-python-fastapi is correct. thanks